# simple_xml_load_string and xml attribute types

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am working with an API at the moment, that accepts XML in a request, however the atrributes of that XML have to particular formats (string, int, boolean, dateTime etc). An example of my XML is as follows,

```
<Property>
    <Address>
        <AddressLine1>str1234</AddressLine1>
        <AddressLine2>str1234</AddressLine2>
        <AddressLine3>str1234</AddressLine3>
        <AddressLine4>str1234</AddressLine4>
        <PostCode>po75xa</PostCode>
        <RoyalMailReference>str1234</RoyalMailReference>
    </Address>
    <PropertyType>DetachedHouse</PropertyType>
    <NumberOfBedrooms>3</NumberOfBedrooms>
    <YearBuilt>1970</YearBuilt>
</Property>
```

The XML is stored in a Laravel view that load in like this,

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string( View::make('samplerequest') );
```

I then send the request to the API (it is via SOAP), the request I get back shows eve that actually gets sent shows every attribute is a string. How can I define what type each attribute is? Or will will `simplexml_load_string()` cast everything into a string?

Comment: How does your `SoapClient::__soapCall()` method call looks like?

Comment: `$response = $quote_soap->call( 'GetComparisonSchemaBound' , array('parameters' => $xml) , $service, $action);`

Comment: You can't pass XML objects as paramters. You have to pass a paramName => value array with scalar data in it.

Comment: So i need to turn my XML into an array?

Comment: Exactly and convert your strings from the XML to data types which are required by the SoapServer. For example `NumberOfBedrooms` to `int`.

Comment: Thanks @TiMESPLiNTER `$xml = simplexml_load_string( View::make('') );
  $xmlcont = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);` returns "String could not be parsed as XML" any ideas why?

Comment: `View::make('')` does not return a valid XML string.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER one more question the SOAP api requests a dateTime datatype, it there a way to cast a value to this, I am setting the datetime with PHP and the array output is saying it is a string

Comment: [See this post here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18718862/1652031) It seems as it does matter what DateTime object is on SoapServer site. If it is a PHP SoapServer it is using the [`DateTime`](http://ch1.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class. If it is not PHP it can be very difficult to pass a valid `DateTime` object.