# How can I pass a DateTime object to a Soap web service written with C# from PHP?

Tags: c#, php, web-services, datetime, soap

I am consuming an API, written with C#, in my PHP application. One of the arguments required for a particular method is of type `DateTime`. I've tried the answers given in [C# DateTime type over web service with PHP & SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718084/c-sharp-datetime-type-over-web-service-with-php-soap), but none of those work.

I'm using the Soap extension. Also, the web service is written by a government agency, and I'm sure everyone who has consumed a government API knows how difficult it is to get them to change their arguments. So, I'd appreciate it if solutions wouldn't contain "talk to them and persuade them".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should actually be pretty simple.

Most Web services write datetime in the SOAP message as an [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) string.  For example, `2014-11-15T18:32:17+00:00`.

Here are several suggestions for writing an ISO 8601 format string with PHP:

- [How to display a date as iso 8601 format with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903203/how-to-display-a-date-as-iso-8601-format-with-php)

  `<?= date("c", strtotime($post[3])) ?>`

  ... or ...

  `new DateTime('17 Oct 2008'))->format('c');`

STRONG SUGGESTION:

Get a copy of SoapUI and *look at* the actual SOAP message being passed between your PHP server and your C#/SOAP server:

- http://www.soapui.org/